# C# WPF: How to reduce thickness of lines between tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs, tabcontrol

I want a mostly unmodified tabcontrol that matches the style of the program I'm creating a plugin for. My issue is that, by default, the tabcontrol tabs seem to have a border that sits inside the extents of the tab, which create a double border where the inactive tabs meet. I want this border to be a single line, the same thickness as the at the top of the tab (I am using a top, right alignment).

Unfortunately, the words I am using to describe this in Google and here are making it hard to figure out what property/attribute I need to alter. I have tried using `Margin="-1,0,0,0"` on all but the first tab to "squeeze" them together, but this inadvertently forced all but the first tab to not enlarge when active/selected/pressed.

This is the tabcontrol, largely unmodified with the double border between two inactive tabs that seems to be default appearance:

[image]

This is the build with the `Margin` set to the above values and the desired appearance for the border between two inactive tabs:

[image]

And this is the issue using the `Margin` setting above causes:

[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated! It's likely a very simple fix, but I'm not too familiar with tabcontrols and looking through the properties hasn't given me the right insight to solve it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to change the BorderThickness of the TabItem's Header is to edit its ControlTemplate. In the design, right click a header and select Edit Template > Edit a Copy. You must edit the MultiDataTrigger that changes the BorderThickness for the TabItem's mainBorder when `IsSelected` is false and `TapStripPlacement` is Top. Locate this code:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Change the value of the mainBorder's BorderThickness to "0,1,1,0". You can then apply the style to each TabItem except the first.